# AppCompat dialog theme

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompat.Light theme for my application and activities and on Android 4.0+ devices my dialogs are white with black text. There is an issue, however, with Android 2.3.3-4.0 devices which are using the same theme but the dialogs are black and the text is also black making it unreadable.

How can I make it so that the dialogs on 2.3.3+ devices are always using a white background?

Comment: Have you tried doing your own Dialog ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html))?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `AlertDialog`, you can replace it with [support.v7.app.AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html) - this will ensure you get consistent material design dialogs on all API7+ devices.